# Need help on this below Sql Query

Tags: sql-server

If employee role ='employee' and (employee role ='mgr' or employee role ='director' or employee role ='ceo' ) then Yes Else No.
Descrition:employee is having more than two roles need to get the details with flag'YES' ,if he having only one role i.e employee need flag as 'NO'.

Sample data in employee table:

```
empno   ename   erole
10  a   emp
10  a   mgr
10  a   dir
10  a   ceo
11  b   emp
12  c   mgr
12  c   emp
13  d   emp
13  d   ceo
14  e   emp
```

need output like below:

```
empno ename Flag 
10    a     yes 
11    b     No 
12    c     yes 
13    d     yes 
14    e     No
```

Comment: please explain what do you want to do here

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: There are multiple ways this could be solved, but here on stackoverflow we expect to see what you've tried first. Please read [ask] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do - because at the moment, you logic expression is saying "if something is equal to two different things simultaneously ..."

Comment: my question is if employee is having more than two roles need to get the details with flag'YES' ,if he having only one role i.e employee need flag as 'NO'.

Comment: Update your question with a proper subject line and insert the explanation into the question instead of posting it as a comment.

Comment: Have you tried anything? You probably want to use `group by` and `count()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CASE to check the count

```
SELECT empno, ename,
    CASE WHEN  COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'No'
    END as Flag
FROM table
GROUP BY empno, ename
```